# How do you know how many existing layers of asphalt on my driveway now?

Tags: driveway, asphalt, paving

I recently got a quote to dig out and replace my asphalt driveway. The quote stated if there were more than 3 layers now there would be an additional charge added to the quote. Is there a way the homeowners can check this themselves?

Comment: Dig a hole though it or dig down right at the edge.  Should be able to count the layers.

Comment: It might not be a bad idea to ask the contractor to take that off the quote. If they give you trouble with that request, I would consider trying to solicit other offers.

Comment: @VtC - "How do I know how many layers of asphalt are in my driveway" doesn't seem to be very opinion based to me. Nor does "Is there a way for a homeowner to determine this?"

Comment: hmm number of layers instead of thickness, that seems strange.

Answer (score 1):

The thickness and strength primarily determine the asphalt pavement strength. Asphalt concretes tend to bond to each other unlike cement concrete, so the number of layers does not seem significant. I would be more impressed if he said it is very thick or very strong (there is a very wide range of strength properties in asphalt mixes). I would get another quote, preferably from a contractor recommended by a friend.